# Android Popup picker?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am looking for the right UI widget to use for this requirement:

When the user clicks a button, a modal list appears, the user clicks and item and then the focus is returned to the active Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check AlertDialog and setSingleChoiceItems on [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a [ContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu).

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a dialog. And you can customize the dialog with custom views as per your needs.

Some help on the dialog http://www.channels.com/episodes/show/6481543/Episode-8-The-Alert-Dialog

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389626/2069407) from another post:

```
CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[] {"red", "green", "blue", "black"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // the user clicked on colors[which]
    }
});
builder.show();
```