# Android: create a popup that has multiple selection options

Tags: android, menu, dialog, popup

I've been searching around trying to figure out how to create a popup or a dialog that has 4 options to choose from.

I see this picture on the Android developer site:

[image]

Does anyone know how to code up something like the one on the right? I don't need any icons next to my text, I just need to be able to select from 4 options.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

You can create a `String` array with the options you want to show there and then pass the array to an `AlertDialog.Builder` with the method `setItems(CharSequence[], DialogInterface.OnClickListener)`.

An example:

```
String[] colors = {"red", "green", "blue", "black"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // the user clicked on colors[which]
    }
});
builder.show();
```

The output (on Android 4.0.3):

[image: Output]

(Background map not included. ;))

Comment: `.create()` is unnecessary here, `.show()` will return the dialog created by the builder and then show it as well

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I really didn't want to implement an xml layout for a simple text menu and could not find an easy way to do this until I stumbled across this post.

Comment: How can we  middle these text and can we set the color inside this text? e.g red shows the red color?? green text displays in green color?

Comment: Note : this example not is multiple, read again tittle from post :)

Comment: Hello, can you also show how I can set actions for specific item selections? Example: I want to let the user change the app language by clicking one of those items (probably using if statement).

Comment: Also, is it possible to add a subtitle under the title of the dialog?

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    final String[] fonts = {
        "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Huge"
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TopicDetails.this);
    builder.setTitle("Select a text size");
    builder.setItems(fonts, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {@
        Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if ("Small".equals(fonts[which])) {
                Toast.makeText(TopicDetails.this, "you nailed it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ("Medium".equals(fonts[which])) {
                Toast.makeText(TopicDetails.this, "you cracked it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ("Large".equals(fonts[which])) {
                Toast.makeText(TopicDetails.this, "you hacked it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ("Huge".equals(fonts[which])) {
                Toast.makeText(TopicDetails.this, "you digged it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // the user clicked on colors[which]

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: I think switch(font[which]) is doing it.

Answer (score 6):

The pop ups are nothing but `AlertDialog`.So you just need to create `AlertDialog`, then inflate your desired view using `LayoutInflater` and set the inflated view using `setView()` method of `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 3):

**ALTERNATIVE OPTION**

This is my first post so I'm excited to share my code!
This worked for me:

Place these two lines above the OnCreate event

```
final String[] Options = {"Red", "Blue"};
AlertDialog.Builder window;
```

Place this code on the event that will trigger this

```
window = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
window.setTitle("Pick a color");
window.setItems(Options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(which == 0){
           //first option clicked, do this...

        }else if(which == 1){
           //second option clicked, do this...

        }else{
        //theres an error in what was selected
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hmmm I messed up. I detected that you clicked on : " + which + "?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});

window.show();
```

Comment: Yes much improvement. A switch statement improves more