# Android: How to create a custom dropdown dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I need to create a dialog which drops down from a **clicked position** on the screen.

I have considered using a floating `ContextMenu`, but I need to customize the contents of the dropdown to display my own `views`.

[image: context menu]

I have also considered using a custom `DialogFragment` but this is not subtle enough and interrupts the flow.

[image]

**How can I create something in between?**

A perfect example would be the dropdown dialog used by Duolingo:

[image: good example]

I have also considered just adding a `framelayout` to the point where the user clicks but I'm not sure how to recreate the dept of a `ContextMenu` or how to create a decent animation when the dialog is fading in and out.

I dont want to display a list of options within the dialog, I want to display a custom layout with a number of `textviews` and `buttons`.

Comment: You need to use [Popup Window](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow)

Comment: [See This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389626/5787969) for drop-down dialog list. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check these libraries, it will help you**

https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/BubbleLayout?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3564

https://github.com/piruin/quickaction?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5746

**You can also make it without library:**

1. Create custom dialog
2. Set dialog animation

   ```
   override Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       ...
       Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
       dialog.setWindowAnimations(R.style.anim_dropdown);
       return dialog;
   }
   ```
3. [Changing position of the Dialog on screen android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467026/changing-position-of-the-dialog-on-screen-android)